Can anyone explain the relationship between the seven deadly sins and derivative market
So, my teacher ask me to explain clearly why, how, what derivative tool,. affect to the rise and fall (add charts, data,..) of these events:
-The Enron crisis for Greed
-Nick leeson's gambling for Wrath
-The Long-term Capital Management for Sloth
-The Lehman Brothers scandal for Pride
-Parmalat's scandal for Envy
I'm just learn about derivative market subject for 2 month but my teacher don't care about it. If I can't explain it in my essay, I won't pass this subject. Anyone know please help me.


I am sorry to read that you are about to fail, but this is not really the responsibility of this SE.



This seven sins thing seems to just be a weird obsession of your prof, I doubt people here can easily help you. Just read about the individual cases and write a long student paper on it, while looking for motives in each case that you could link to specific sins? Ask a student peer in the same course to collaborate.

